# showing degree symbol bash/tcl

Tags: bash, sh

im trying to get a login script to display degree symbol but it doesn't display it.

```
Here is the weather.sh
METRIC="1"  # 0 for F, 1 for C
# Fill in form to find your weather code here:
# http://netweather.accuweather.com/signup-page2.asp
# If code has a space remove it or replace it with %20 or a dash; -
LOCCOD="struer"  #Example: NAM|MX|MX009|MEXICO-CITY

if [ "$weather" != "0" ] ; then
  weather=`curl -s http://rss.accuweather.com/rss/liveweather_rss.asp\?metric\=${METRIC}\&locCode\=$LOCCOD \
  | grep -E '<description>(Currently|High)' \
  | sed -e 's/.*<description>\(.*\)/\1/' -e 's/\(.*\) &lt.*/\1/' -e 's/\(&#38;#176;\)//'`
  if [ "`echo "$weather" | wc -l`" -eq "3" ] ; then
    echo "Weather......: `echo "$weather" | head -1`"
    echo "Today........: `echo "$weather" | head -2 | tail -1`"
    echo "Tomorrow.....: `echo "$weather" | tail -1`"
  fi
fi
```

But when i login it only shows: `&#176;C`

but if i do: `echo $'\xc2\xb0'C` in putty, it displays fine?

what gives, and how do i solve it?

Comment: '&#176;' is an HTML-ism that the shell won't recognize or interpret. You need to replace it with that sequence you showed to work in your `echo` example.

Comment: For what it's worth, `grep 'x' | sed 'y'` can usually be refactored to `sed '/x/!d;y'`. See also [useless use of `grep`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#grep)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This comment](https://superuser.com/q/1506888/432690#comment2277578_1506888) is right.

> `&#176;` is an HTML-ism that the shell won't recognize or interpret. You need to replace it with that sequence you showed to work in your `echo` example.

At least two ways:

1. Specific way: replace this particular string using `sed` you already have. Add this script:

   ```
   -e 's/&#176;/°/'
   ```
2. General way: expand many possible HTML-isms using `recode`:

   ```
   curl … | grep … | sed … | recode html
   ```

   In general you may want to use `recode html` just after `curl`.

Answer (score 0):

Hope its okay to reuse the topic :)

```
 echo "  \e[35mWeather.......:\e[0m `echo "\e[36m$weather\e[0m" | head -1`"
    echo "  \e[35mToday.........:\e[0m `echo "\e[36m$weather\e[0m" | head -2 | tail -1`"
    echo "  \e[35mTomorrow......:\e[0m `echo "\e[36m$weather\e[0m" | tail -1`"
```

The above has some kind of error, the first line shows the right color but the next to lines doesn't

[image: https://imgur.com/fmFjmZm]